# JMeter regular expression extractor from a variable

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to extract a number from `string` in single quotes.

For example: '0000123' in JMeter. This `string` comes from a CSV file configured in CSV data config.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant regular expression extractor configuration will look like:

- Apply to: `JMeter Variable`. Provide variable name which holds that 0000123 value.
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, you can re-use the same variable name - it will be overwritten.
- Regular Expression: `(\d+)`
- Template: `$1$`
- Other fields can be left as they are

See image below for configuration applied example and [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) guide for more information on the domain.

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Comment: The link to blazemeter is wrong - you don't get the page you wanted